# Sending mail via PHP, but checking if form is valid via JS, a little confused

Tags: php, javascript

I need to check if a form field is empty, if its not, I need the JS to return a value and the form to get submitted via PHP, it will then be sent to another page where the mail is composed and sent etc, I can do that.

The issue is submitting the form on validation, here is what I have:

```
  <script>
function popup()
{

if (document.getElementById("email").value == "") {

alert("Please enter a email adress");
return false;

}
else

return true; // this is where i have issues the issue, it returns true, but how do i submit the form when it returns true
}
      </script>
```

HTML form:

```
<form action="email_func.php" class="signup_form" data-remote="true" id="signup_form" method="post" >

<input class="txt accent-color colorize_border-color required" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Indtast din E-mail" data-label-text="Email" type="email">

<input class="submit button big btn" id="submit_button" name="submit" value="abc" onclick="popup()">

</form>
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Try explaining more what your problem is and what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick="return popup()"
```

will do the trick.

Comment: Remember, this script will *not* be triggered if the form is submitted by pressing the `<enter>` key inside the email field, *only* when *clicking* the button

Comment: not to put it into input onclick, but into <form onsubmit="return popup()">

Answer (score 0):

onclick event should not be placed in the input tag, but in the form tag. So use this:

```
    <form action="email_func.php" class="signup_form" data-remote="true" id="signup_form" method="post" onclick="return popup()">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you might be looking but i am not very sure

```
<form action="email_func.php" class="signup_form" data-remote="true" id="signup_form" method="post" onsubmit="return popup();">
```